# A word for asserting your opinion then attempting to end the conversation so the other person can't express theirs?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Looking for a word which describes an attempt to simultaneously assert one's opinion but not allow the other to express theirs. For example, in a conversation about a person, one may express their opinion and then notify the other participant that they can no longer carry on this conversation — so that they wouldn't need to form a proper response to a disagreement.

Comment: I think there are too many associated factors here. The person must be both opinionated / argumentative, *and* a bully. Also he probably has to have higher social standing than the people with whom he's unilaterally [***guillotining the debate***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22guillotine+the+debate%22) (preventing any further discussion). Informally, you might say he's ***laying down the law*** and ***having the final word***.

Comment: All I would add to your comment is that you should perhaps have been gender-inclusive throughout!

Comment: @WS2 The Karens have landed.

Comment: May I ask a question derived from the text of the question? Is it correct to use the form "wouldn't" in "so that they wouldn't need to form..." and not "won't"? And isn't it a singular possessive pronoun (his/her) that is needed in: "...allow the other to express theirs", "...one may express their opinion"?

Comment: @Eugene - I think it’s neither *wouldn’t* nor * won’t*. Try ***can’t** form* instead.

Comment: @Jim Thank you very much.